# GlassFish randomly selects wrong JCA ConnectionFactory for Injection

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4, jca

I am in the process of writing a JCA Resource Adapter for FTP and SFTP. As my goal is to be able to use one protocol completely independent from the other, I have two different ManagedConnectionFactory classes, one for each protocol. Both have different ConnectionDefinition annotations; the Glassfish domain.xml contains a resource definition for the FTP Adapter but not for the SFTP Adapter. Now, when I inject the `FTPConnectionFactory` into an EJB, I sometimes get an InjectionException as WELD tries to inject the `SFTPConnectionFactory` instead (this is of course consistent during a run of the appserver; I either consistently get the right or the wrong one). Removing the ConnectionDefinition annotation for the SFTP adapter seems to fix the problem.

So, Questions:

- How can I fix this and make Glassfish inject the correct class? Can this be caused by a problem in my code or is this a Glassfish issue?
- According to the spec it is legal for a RA to have multiple ConnectionDefinition annotations, as well as multiple *instances* of a class implementing ManagedConnectionFactory; but I couldn't find any information about having multiple *different* classes implementing ManagedConnectionFactory inside of the same Resource Adapter. Glassfish clearly seems to have a problem with it - is this explicitly allowed or disallowed somewhere?

---

The ConnectionDefinition (with FTP replaced by SFTP for the SFTP case):

```
@ConnectionDefinition(connectionFactory = FTPConnectionFactory.class,
    connectionFactoryImpl = FTPConnectionFactoryImpl.class,
    connection = FTPConnection.class, connectionImpl = FTPConnectionImpl.class)
```

The FTP and SFTP Factory and ManagedConnection classes share common ancestors but are not directly related - but this doesn't seem to matter as completely separating the implementations makes no difference.

The `domain.xml` snippet:

```
<resource-adapter-config resource-adapter-name="ftpconnector" thread-pool-ids="thread-pool-1" />
<connector-connection-pool name="jca/ftpConnectorPool"
    resource-adapter-name="ftpconnector"
    connection-definition-name="foo.bar.ftp.FTPConnection"
    transaction-support="NoTransaction" match-connections="false" />
<connector-resource pool-name="jca/ftpConnectorPool" jndi-name="jca/ftpConnector" />
```

And the injected field:

```
@Resource(lookup = "jca/ftpConnector")
private FTPConnectionFactory ftpConnectionFactory;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: This was caused by an incorrectly configured Connection Pool, where `connection-definition-name` does not point to a class implementing `ConnectionFactory`. The observed behaviour is IMO a bug and has been reported [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21075).

---

While trying to reproduce this issue with Adam Biens [connectorz](https://github.com/AdamBien/connectorz) Filesystem Resource Adapter (by adding a second set of classes and another connection definition), I found I could only reproduce the behaviour if the `connector-connection-pool` in the domain.xml is incorrectly defined: If I changed the `connection-definition-name` to point to a nonexistent class, Glassfish would randomly take one of the two defined connectors. Doublechecking my Connection Pool, I found out that I mistakenly used the Connection class instead of the ConnectionFactory class in the xml. So when the attribute does not point to a class implementing the `ConnectionFactory` interface, Glassfish seems to randomly choose any class from the Resource Adapter which implements `ConnectionFactory`, without even printing an error message.